# Run a .exe file from bash wsl but it cannot run

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm sorry for the title as I don't know how to phrase this better.

So I want to run an exe file from bash. I'm using WSL. I know that I just need to specify the path and it runs, but the program I'm trying to run cannot be run from a command line shell. I'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/ililim/dual-key-remap/releases), which basically remap my caps lock key to control and backspace.

So if I double click the executable it runs and my keys are swapped.

But if I run the exe from bash (or even powershell.exe or cmd.exe), the program just opens in my terminal and I can't use my shell anymore. I have to ctrl+c to kill the process and thus not running the executable. This is what I mean by I "cannot be run from a command line shell".

I'm sorry if this isn't the right place to post, but I'm not sure where to post. Maybe this is a bug from the program itself, but I'm not sure, and thank you in advance!

Comment: Run the `dual-key-remap.exe` [asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2368137/3439404) (e.g. like `Start-Process 'dual-key-remap.exe'` from Powershell or `start "" dual-key-remap.exe` from `cmd`).

Comment: Thank you a lot! This is exactly what I was searching for.